# PHP MySQL insert doesn't work and I can't find any errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this PHP code and I'm trying to insert data into my database. It doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why. I tried to echo mysqli_error, but it didn't show me any errors. I also echoed the query and it worked just fine when I ran it in phpmyadmin directly.

**Form**

```
<form method="POST" action="images.php?#werk" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h6>Voeg nieuwe afbeelding toe</h6>
                    <div class="file-field input-field">
                        <div class="btn">
                            <span>Bestand</span>
                            <input name="install" type="file">
                        </div>
                        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                            <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <textarea id="textarea1" name="caption" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                        <label for="textarea1">Beschrijving</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit2">Voeg toe
                            <i class="material-icons right">add</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**PHP**

```
include "includes/connect.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
addInstallation($_POST['caption'], "install");
}
```

**connect.php**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $usernameDB, $password, $usernameDB);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

**addInstallation**

```
function addInstallation($caption, $name){
$target_dir = "../in-progress.johnkok.com/img/installations/";
if($_FILES[$name]["size"] > 0){
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES[$name]["name"]);
    $uploadOK = 1;
    $image_type = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES[$name]["tmp_name"]);

    if($check !== false){
        $uploadOK = 1;
    }
    else{
        $feedback2 = "Bestand is geen afbeelding.";
        $uploadOK = 0;
    }

    if($uploadOK !== 0){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
        $target_file = "img/installations/" . basename($_FILES[$name]["name"]);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `Installations`(`caption`, `image_path`) VALUES ('$caption','$target_file')");
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

}

Comment: are you sure that your script pass the condition "if($uploadOK !== 0)" ?

Comment: what is error you get ?

Comment: move_uploaded_file seems to work just fine

Comment: You aren't exposing the `$conn` variable to your function. Your call to mysqli_query is likely failing but you never check for errors.

Comment: did you debug query ? i mean echo  $query without use of mysqli_query(). and fire that echoed query to database.

Comment: @Dave that's it, thanks! Another similar function works just fine without exposing $conn that's why i thought it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php file add the $conn variable to the things you pass.

```
include "includes/connect.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
addInstallation($_POST['caption'], "install",$conn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include connection file in your addInstallation file.
just example :-

```
include "includes/connect.php";
function addInstallation($caption, $name){
// some code
}
```